# One to one and many to many representation of entites in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So i was about to use sqlserver through entity framework and then I got an email saying azure just raised prices on the Azure SQL Elastic db's, again!. Any way am going with mongodb and i need help translating this fluent api to a mongo document?

```
public CourseMappings()
                {
                    HasMany<User>(s => s.Student)
                        .WithMany(c => c.Course);
                }

 public AddressMappings()
            {

                HasRequired(c => c.Student)
                .WithRequiredDependent(u => u.Address);
            }


public StudentMapping()
            {

                HasRequired(c => c.Address)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(u => u.Student);

            }
```

Got three tables, student, address and courses, how do i model this in Mongodb?I know address will be embedded in student for a 1:1 relationship that i have figured out. Question is can it be done in one document(an example) or will the courses be a separate document with an StudentId for a many to many relationship with students?

Comment: What is your query acces pattern? Would the application access the data by student or course?

Comment: Access will be by student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data model in MongoDB is very much dependent on the "Query Access Pattern" of the application. As I understand from you, your application access the data by student id or by student data. I would recommend to have only one collection. The collection schema data model would be something like below:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57971c2b4895ddf87c8747ea"),
    "studentid" : 1,
    "studentname" : "name",
    "address" : {
        "name" : "street name",
        "addressline1" : "line 1",
        "addressline2" : "line 2",
        "post code" : "GRUHFYN"
    },
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "courseid" : 1,
            "coursename" : "science"
        }, 
        {
            "courseid" : 2,
            "coursename" : "english"
        }, 
        {
            "courseid" : 3,
            "coursename" : "Maths"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Student Model with data types]

Comment: Okay, so address will be a type `List<>`. How will course be represented as a POCO?

Comment: Would you kindly POCO the whole document and save others like me in the future please?

Comment: Address is not a list. In MongoDB terms, it is just a sub-document. Course is a list as a student can be enrolled for multiple courses. Please note that there is no constraints concept present in MongoDB similar to RDBMS. So I am not sure whether I can put together a POCO as you suggested. I have attached the MongoDB datatypes of each field for more information.